# Upgrade to 14.04 causes "the disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present" - Computer can't start: Live Disc Repair Option?

Tags: 14.04, gparted, swap, live-cd, cryptsetup

I am a relative newbie who used Ubuntu 12 a few years back on an old Dell to install Bitcoin Armory for Cold Storage. When recently deciding to retrieve a coin, I also took it out of storage, i.e. plugged in a WiFi card to upgrade into Ubuntu 14.04. However, when rebooting, I experienced the /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 screen, and when the OS advances to the login screen, the mouse and keyboard lag are over a minute, making the system unusable.

As I've had time to research the over the past two weeks, it's obviously an encryption issue resulting from upgrading all recommended app and system components. However, this old Dell only has 1GB of RAM, and most solutions assume you can get into the system to fix it, so this newbie has struggled to learn to use a LiveCD to mount my install and get this far:

I was surprised that Cryptswap is already installed on my impacted instance. I also tried reinstalling Grub with no impact. From the live CD, I don't have permission to browse into the Root directory, as I was hoping to back up my Home Directory and reinstall Kubuntu as a last resort. If there is something obvious I'm missing, like needed to create some sort of swap for cryptsetup to get past this warning screen at startup, I appreciate any and all recommendations. Thanks!

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list  

device      fs_type   label   mount point             UUID  
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
/dev/loop0  squashfs  /rofs  
/dev/sda1   ntfs              /media/kubuntu/B2003C35003BFF43 B2003C35003BFF43  
/dev/sdb2   ext4              /media/kubuntu/216f8aff-d396-458e-a682-b4f9e7ba0e13 216f8aff-d396-458e-a682-b4f9e7ba0e13  
/dev/sdb5   ntfs      500GB   /media/kubuntu/500GB    01CCB9D34BD0E0C0  
/dev/sr0    iso9660   Kubuntu /cdrom  

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt  
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ ls /mnt  
bin  boot  cdrom  dev  etc  home  initrd.img  initrd.img.old  lib  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  vmlinuz  vmlinuz.old

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ cat /mnt/etc/lsb-release  
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu  
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04  
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty  
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"  

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo -i  

root@kubuntu:~# apt-get install cryptsetup  
Reading package lists.. Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
cryptsetup is already the newest version.  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: The package for cryptswap may have been removed during the upgrade, if this is the case you could chroot into the installation from the LiveCD and install the package.

Answer (score -1):

I had to give up after finding my paper backup for the bitcoins. Before that, I tried reinstalling GRUB, created a new SWAP, and nothing worked. I wish anyone else with this issue the best of luck.